# App crashing on initializing UItabbarController for below iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on some one else's project and while working I have found an issue. Issue is that app is crashing on below iOS 13.0 for using UITabBarAppearance but when I search for UITabBarAppearance in project it does not show any code containing UITabBarAppearance which means that we have not used any thing regarding tab bar appearance although there is a class for UITabbarController and crash accours while initializing this controller
I am posting screen shots of crash detail, where crash is occurring and that class below, I hope that it will be enough to debug the problem

**Crash Details**
[image]

**Crash Occurence**
[image]

**UITabbarController Class**
[image]

**TabBar in storyboard**
[image]

**TabBar Attribute Inspector**

[image]

Comment: From code we can see that it crashes on initialization from a storyboard. Could you show us configuration of the view controller there? I guess, it uses some features introduced in iOS 13. Another thing to check, does Xcode show you any warning about something introduced in iOS 13 being used on prior versions?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the main storyboard and yes we are using a scanner which are limited and only usable for iOS 13.0 and above other than that there is not any warning regarding iOS version check.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of Attribute Inspector? Something probably hides there.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of Attribute Inspector. There is another thing that I'm using cocoa pod of LGSideMenuController and the initialization which is causing crash has been called in SetupSideMenu in App Delegate

Comment: So, I guess you found the reason then? A 3rd party library that crashes on iOS 12?

Comment: I have tried by uninstalling the 3rd party but it is still crashing

Comment: Got the solution thanks lazarevzubov.

Answer (score 1):

You were right lazarevzubov, the answer was hidden in the attribute inspector. I just had to uncheck both standard and scroll edge in the Appearance of the attribute inspector and it started working fine.
if someone get the same problem for navigation bar the same solution will work for navigation bar too.
[image]